# Is it possible to use 'if-case' in place of a switch that has a coma delimited list as a case?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, pattern-matching, if-case

Swift 2 introduced `if-case` which is supposed to be a more terse way of expressing a switch that only has a few cases. I'm wondering if there is a way of expressing a switch statement with a comma delimited list as an `if-case`.

```
let (a,b) = (1,0)

switch (a,b) {

case (1,0), (0,1), (1,1):
    print("true")
default:
    print("false")
}
```

**What I've tried:**

```
if case (a,b) = (1,0) {
    // works
}

if case (a,b) = (1,0), (0,1), (1,1) {
    // doesn't
}
```

**This compiles but returns false for the `(a,b)` tuple:**

```
if case (a,b) = (1,0),
case (a,b) = (0,1),
case (a,b) = (1,1) {
    print("if case true")
} else {
    print("if case false")
}
```

**What I'd like to see:**

I'd like to see an approach to shorten the above switch statement into a single `if-case`.

### My Question

Is it possible to use `if-case` in place of a switch that has a coma delimited list as a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after nearly a month. This is the closest I could get to satisfying the comma delimited list question. This actually satisfies the same requirement but in a different way.

```
let tuple = (1,0)

if case (0...1, 0...1) = tuple where !(a == 0 && b == 0) { return true }
else { return false }
```